# ubuntu+nginx+fastcgi php owner

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx, fastcgi

how to set up different owner for php? now it runs from www-data, i need to setup it runs from myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using spawn-fcgi to spawn the PHP process, just add "-u <username>" to the spawn-fcgi command.